# Bug in Chrome or bad CSS? (anchor with visibility hidden)

Tags: css, google-chrome, visibility, hidden

Test this simple line in any HTML:

```
<a href="anything"><span style="visibility:hidden;">insible text here</span></a>
```

(you can test it directly from here: http://jsfiddle.net/wqS3E/ )

In Firefox and IE you can click the link (even more, you can see the default underline decoration).
But in Chrome (v 13.0.782.220 ) is not possible to click/see the link.

Is this a bug in Chrome or my CSS is not correct?

I have a `<li>` element with a background image, and some `<li>` are links, and I want to be able to click those links, but I don't want they visibile because I want to show the background image in `<li>` (and I don't want to brake the HTML markup), so this is what I have:

```
<ul>
    <li>
       <a href="link"><span class="invisible">some text</span></a>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>

.invisible {
   visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Verified in Chrome 14 and Safari 5.1.

Comment: When i add a background-color to the link, it's there and clickable in Chrome.  But without some visible aspect to it, yeah, looks like it's not rendering.

Comment: yes, I've noticed that too @cHao. Even more, if you open the Developer tools from Chrome, and add a background color there, you can see and click the link, now disable the background color again, and you can still clicking the link !. Really weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a standard behavior for invisible stuff inside an `<a>`.

However, i've noticed that setting the `display` to either `block` or `inline-block` makes the link clickable in Chrome.  Not sure about other browsers, but if they already display it, that shouldn't break it.

Comment: Yes, adding "display:inline-block;" to the anchor element solves the problem, thanks cHao ! I think the CSS is not wrong then, and it's a bug in Chrome, I will report it.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting the `<span>` around the `<a>` instead of otherwise?

```
<span class="invisible"><a href="link">some text</a></span>
```

Comment: Is the link still clickable if it's invisible?

Comment: Not in firefox 6 or chrome 14

Comment: Kinda defeats the purpose, then, doesn't it?  :)

Comment: No, in that way you can't click the link in any browser, not only Chrome (and it seems Safari has the same behavior according to @BoltClock). Remember that I want the anchor (I mean I want to click the link) but not the content of the anchor (because I want the image in my <li>)

Comment: I think you need to re-think your question, then.

Comment: @Enrique: Chrome and Safari both use WebKit as the rendering engine, hence the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Logically the link should be clickable. Setting `visibility:invisible` should do just that, make it invisible, but otherwise not affect function.

As an analogy, if Chrome's behaviour were correct then the Active Camouflage should make you invulnerable in Halo.

Overall, seems like a bug in Chrome to me. Especially since Firefox agrees with IE - that doesn't happen often!