# Occasional Failure of Pointer State on Anchors in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, cursor, hover

### Decision to Close:

I've decided to close this question as it denotes a behavior that is not currently observable with the more recent versions of Google Chrome, and is no longer an issue that requires mitigation.

---

### Problem:

For a long time, I've been noticing that when hovering over anchor elements in Chrome, the cursor will remain in the default (arrow) state rather than switching to the pointer (hand) state. I have not observed this behavior when viewing sites in Safari, so I'm not certain this is a webkit issue.

---

### Questions:

What's causing this? What are the workarounds?

---

### Evidence:

I've found this behavior will happen...

- less often after the page is loaded.
- more often while the page is still loading.
- more often, if not exclusively, when `a` elements have a `display` property declaration.
- regardless of the `cursor: pointer` property being declared (although, I could be wrong).

Note the mouse behavior on this example when viewing in Chrome:

- The main navigation of this site: http://css-tricks.com/

**Suspicions:**
Chrome has an issue handling `a` elements with a `display` property declared with a value that differs from the default `inline`. I also suspect that declaring the `position` property on `a` elements with a value that differs from the default `static` may be contributing to the problem.

**Possibly Related:**

- [Chrome hover custom cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094221/chrome-hover-custom-cursor/)
- [Bug in Chrome or bad CSS? (anchor with visibility hidden)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543696/bug-in-chrome-or-bad-css-anchor-with-visibility-hidden)
- http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=93240

Comment: File a bug report at http://new.crbug.com/

Comment: I've also noticed this behavior

Answer (score 2):

Did it happen when your chrome dev tools was open ?

If so, maybe you should disable "Emulate Touch events" in the Overrides Settings of the dev tool.

Cheers

Comment: Not at all. This behavior occurred on fresh installs of Chrome.

Comment: @gmeben Are you sure? Unclicking "Emulate Touch events" in the "Overrides" section of the Chrome developer tools (as -@Ludovic suggests) fixed the problem for me. Wow that had been driving me crazy for months! Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad if that solved your issue. However, I'm not certain that "Emulate touch events" is checked by default in a fresh installation of Chrome. I re-installed last month and that option was already unchecked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me before, and I realized putting a positioning to the element will fix it. For ex:

```
header a.logo{
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    height: 28px;
    width: 28px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-indent: -9999em;
    display: block;
}
```

Hope this helps.